# How to use Pyqt to start one process after another finishes?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qprocess

I would like to run several cmd files using Pyqt5. I am able to currently run only one cmd file...here is a snippet of the code:

```
def run(self):
    self.process = QProcess(self)
    self.process.started.connect(lambda: self.statusUpdate('Started'))
    self.process.finished.connect(lambda: self.statusUpdate('Finished'))
    self.process.start('test.cmd')

def statusUpdate(self, event):
    print(event)
    self.status = event
```

Here is the simple cmd file I want to test with:

```
echo TEST
echo TEST
echo TEST
PAUSE
```

I noticed that even though the cmd file finishes, it never prints 'Finished'

How can I start another cmd file after the first one finishes?

Comment: show the *cmd files*

Comment: @eyllanesc The cmd file is running some image processing on another file but how would that affect anything? When it finishes, it does say "Press any key to continue"....would that be the issue? I don't even know how to get it to start another cmd process (since it doesn't even print the 'finish')

Comment: I just want to review that, but without the .cmd I can not reproduce your problem, you could create dummy cmds that reproduce the problem.

Comment: @eyllanesc I edited the question and added a simple cmd file I created just now. Does the same thing and never prints "Finished" (although it prints "Started")

Comment: As I review PAUSE, it only finishes executing if you press certain keys. Do not you think that if you do not press any of those keys the .cmd will not stop executing? Do not you think that's the problem?, why do you use PAUSE?

Comment: You are right, removing the pause causes the 'Finish' to be printed. However, how do I start the second process? I tried doing another `self.process.start('test2.cmd')` but that never gets executed

Comment: Is the test2.cmd similar to the .cmd it shows?

Comment: Yeah it is similar (without the pause).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem, a class is implemented that executes the commands sequentially, that is, it ends one task and executes the next one until all the commands are executed.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from functools import partial


class SequentialManager(QtCore.QObject):
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    resultsChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QByteArray)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SequentialManager, self).__init__(parent)
        self.process = QtCore.QProcess(self)
        self.process.finished.connect(self.handleFinished)
        self.process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.onReadyReadStandardOutput)

    def start(self, commands):
        self._commands = iter(commands)
        self.fetchNext()

    def fetchNext(self):
        try:
            command = next(self._commands)
        except StopIteration:
            return False
        else:
            self.process.start(command)
        return True

    def onReadyReadStandardOutput(self):
        result = self.process.readAllStandardOutput()
        self.resultsChanged.emit(result)

    def handleFinished(self):
        if not self.fetchNext():
            self.finished.emit()


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.te = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.te.setReadOnly(True)
        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start processes")
        vlay.addWidget(self.te)
        vlay.addWidget(btn)

        manager = SequentialManager(self)
        manager.resultsChanged.connect(self.onResultsChanged)

        commands = ["test1.cmd", "test2.cmd"]
        btn.clicked.connect(partial(manager.start, commands))

    def onResultsChanged(self, result):
        self.te.append(str(result, "utf-8"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What if I already have a class for the layout and buttons? Can I put `manager = SequentialManager()` inside the central widget?

Comment: @Jess SequentialManager is not a widget, use it as I have used it.

Comment: I meant when calling SequentialManager(): I did this in my central widget:         `manager = SequentialManager(self)`
`commands = ['test1.cmd', 'test2.cmd']`
`manager.start(commands)` I kept the SequentialManager class basically the same. When I hit RUN in my gui, nothing happens?

Comment: @Jess use `manager = SequentialManager(self)` `commands = ['test1.cmd', 'test2.cmd']` `manager.start(commands)`

Comment: @Jess Do not modify SequentialManager, if you do I can not guarantee that it works.

Comment: thanks for your help so far. I edited the previous comment before I saw your comment. So even when I use `manager.start(commands)` the commands don't execute (however it does do editing that the script calls for before the SequentialManager(), I checked the timestamp and the files were updated)

Comment: @Jess if a certain part is executed, the error is probably due to permissions or other reasons, unfortunately, without knowing what you are doing, I will not be able to help you.